Installing jax and jaxlib for CUDA V9.1.85
I am using Python 3.8.0 and CUDA 9.1.85 (CUDA compilation tools, release 9.1) (or not? see below). Unfortunately, I do not have administrative privileges, so I am unable to upgrade either of them.
I am having trouble installing JAX and jaxlib with these versions. How can I proceed?
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85

nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 15 13:22:26 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA TITAN RTX    Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   31C    P8    18W / 280W |      8MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA TITAN RTX    Off  | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   35C    P8    25W / 280W |     21MiB / 24219MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1861      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      1861      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 16MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I have tried installing JAX and jaxlib using the standard commands pip install jax and pip install -U "jax[cuda9]", but I just can't get it to work.
I have also tried...
pip install jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda91 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
Looking in links: https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda91 (from versions: 0.1.52+cuda100, 0.1.52+cuda101, 0.1.52+cuda102, 0.1.52+cuda110, 0.1.55+cuda100, 0.1.55+cuda101, 0.1.55+cuda102, 0.1.55+cuda110, 0.1.56+cuda100, 0.1.56+cuda101, 0.1.56+cuda102, 0.1.56+cuda110, 0.1.56+cuda111, 0.1.57+cuda101, 0.1.57+cuda102, 0.1.57+cuda110, 0.1.57+cuda111, 0.1.58+cuda101, 0.1.58+cuda102, 0.1.58+cuda110, 0.1.58+cuda111, 0.1.59+cuda101, 0.1.59+cuda102, 0.1.59+cuda110, 0.1.59+cuda111, 0.1.60+cuda101, 0.1.60+cuda102, 0.1.60+cuda110, 0.1.60+cuda111, 0.1.61+cuda101, 0.1.61+cuda102, 0.1.61+cuda110, 0.1.61+cuda111, 0.1.61+cuda112, 0.1.62+cuda101, 0.1.62+cuda102, 0.1.62+cuda110, 0.1.62+cuda111, 0.1.62+cuda112, 0.1.63+cuda101, 0.1.63+cuda102, 0.1.63+cuda110, 0.1.63+cuda111, 0.1.63+cuda112, 0.1.64+cuda101, 0.1.64+cuda102, 0.1.64+cuda110, 0.1.64+cuda111, 0.1.64+cuda112, 0.1.65+cuda101, 0.1.65+cuda102, 0.1.65+cuda110, 0.1.65+cuda111, 0.1.65+cuda112, 0.1.66+cuda101, 0.1.66+cuda102, 0.1.66+cuda110, 0.1.66+cuda111, 0.1.67+cuda101, 0.1.67+cuda102, 0.1.67+cuda110, 0.1.67+cuda111, 0.1.68+cuda101, 0.1.68+cuda102, 0.1.68+cuda110, 0.1.68+cuda111, 0.1.69+cuda101, 0.1.69+cuda102, 0.1.69+cuda110, 0.1.69+cuda111, 0.1.70+cuda101, 0.1.70+cuda102, 0.1.70+cuda110, 0.1.70+cuda111, 0.1.71+cuda102, 0.1.71+cuda110, 0.1.71+cuda111, 0.1.72+cuda111, 0.1.73+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.1.73+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.1.74+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.1.74+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.1.75+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.1.75+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.1.76+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.1.76+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.0+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.0+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.2+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.2+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.5+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.5+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.7+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.7+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.8+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.8+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.10+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.10+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.14+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.14+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.15+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.15+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.18+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.18+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.20+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.20+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.22+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.22+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.24+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.24+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.3.25+cuda11.cudnn805, 0.3.25+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.1+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.1+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.2+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.2+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.3+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.3+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.4+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.4+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.6, 0.4.6+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.6+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.7, 0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn82, 0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.7+cuda12.cudnn88, 0.4.9, 0.4.9+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.9+cuda12.cudnn88, 0.4.10, 0.4.10+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.10+cuda12.cudnn88, 0.4.11, 0.4.11+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.11+cuda12.cudnn88, 0.4.12, 0.4.12+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.12+cuda12.cudnn89, 0.4.13, 0.4.13+cuda11.cudnn86, 0.4.13+cuda12.cudnn89)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda91


That version seems to be compatible with CUDA 9.2. So you could try building from source, as there don't seem to be precompiled binaries for such old CUDA.

Your driver clearly supports CUDA 11.4 and you only need root privileges to install the driver. The toolkit can be installed in your home-directory without installing the driver coming with it (package managers do so all the time).

They even tell you that you should let pip install CUDA (the toolkit) for you.

CUDA 9 is quite old, and newer versions of JAX do not support it (looking at the JAX Changelog, CUDA 9.2 support was dropped in version 0.1.49, released in June 2020).
You could try installing JAX v0.1.48, but I doubt it would work for you: most modern JAX code and packages would not be runnable because a lot has changed in the package in four and a half years.
Your best bet is to use a newer CUDA. If you're unable to update your system CUDA, you can always use pip-installed CUDA following the installation instructions for JAX v0.4.13, which was the last version to support Python 3.8:
pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]==0.4.13" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

But even this is over two years old now, and Python 3.8 is past its end-of-life. You'll have a much better experience if you can update to a supported Python version (currently Python 3.9 or newer), in which case you could use the standard installation path for JAX + CUDA12 wheels:
pip install jax[cuda12]

